# XMPP library For J2ME

Tags: java-me, xmpp

I have searched a lot. But, didn't find any XMPP library for J2ME. Please tell me, how can I create an application which uses XMPP in J2ME? I tried libraries like JXA, Microjabber. It gives error because of unavailability of some classes. Please tell me if any XMPP library is available for J2ME. Thank you.